# ./configure doesn't work on python 3.8.2 on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, configuration, configure

I am trying to execute the code:

```
./configure \
        --prefix "$(dirname $(pwd))" \
        --with-openssl=$(openssl version -d | sed  -r 's/OPENSSLDIR: "([^"]*)"/\1/') \
    && make && make install
popd
```

this error is recived:

```
  File "<ipython-input-7-f69304efaff4>", line 1
    ./configure
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This code should be executed in bash shell, not python

Comment: when i try to execute it on the shell the error "'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." is shown

Comment: there should be a file named configure, and probably you are using Windows and command is for UNIX

Comment: Do you know any equivalent to windows?

Answer (score 0):

It should be executed in bash shell but as i am using windows it was not possible.

In this code i was trying to install FreeTDS and after download the stable realease and the binaries for windows I was able to install it by using the windows powershell to run the .ps1 file